# A ball contained in the image of a diffeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove the following.

> If $\varphi: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a diffeomorphism such that for $x\in B(0,r) \subset U$, $$ |\varphi(x)-x| < \epsilon|x|, $$
>   then $$ B(0,(1-\epsilon)r) \subset \varphi(B(0,r)). $$

I think I saw somewhere that this can be proven even without requiring $\varphi$ to be a diffeomorphism, but I believe there should be a simple proof using this stronger assumption.

**Attempt 1:** Since $\varphi$ is diffeomorphism it is in particular open, and so we can certainly find a $\delta > 0$ so that
$$ B(0,\delta) \subset \varphi(B(0,r)), $$
but I don't know how to relate this $\delta$ to $\epsilon$ and $r$.

**Attempt 2:** By letting $y = \varphi(x)$ and rewriting the assumption, one can obtain that
$$ |y-\varphi^{-1}(y)| < \epsilon|\varphi^{-1}(y)| \quad\Rightarrow\quad (1-\epsilon)|x| < |\varphi(x)|, $$
given that $x \in B(0,r)$. However this is not good enough since I would like to squeeze $(1-\epsilon)r$ into the final inequality somehow.

Could someone provide a hint?

**EDIT:** It might be worth pointing out that for my purposes it would suffice to show that  $$ B(0,(1-c\epsilon)r) \subset \varphi(B(0,r)), $$
for some constant $c$ independent of $r$.

**EDIT 2:** Here's a way to do it.
Suppose $y \in B(0, (1-\epsilon)r)$, and put $x = \varphi^{-1}(y)$. We want to show that $x \in B(0,r)$. From the estimate in Attempt 2, we have
$$ |x| < \frac{|y|}{1-\epsilon} < \frac{r(1-\epsilon)}{1-\epsilon} = r, $$
which gives the result.

Comment: Usually, things like this are proved by applying the contraction mapping principle to show that you can solve $\phi(x)=y$ for any $y\in B(0,(1-\epsilon)r)$ with $x\in \overline{B(0,r)}$. Perhaps you need to shrink $r$ arbitrarily before you take the closure of the ball.

Comment: I was trying to avoid the contraction principle. I thought that assuming that $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism might enable me to do so.

Comment: An adaptation of the proof from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3218803/is-a-differentiable-but-not-c1-function-f-mathbbrn-rightarrow-mathb works if $\phi$ is differentiable with nowhere vanishing derivative, and $|z| \leq (1-2\epsilon)r$, I think. From the proof of the inverse function theorem, I think you can assume that $\phi-Id$ is $\epsilon$-Lipschitz continuous to get something approaching your claim.